# How do I draw the Cho Ku Rei Symbol in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do I draw the Cho Ku Rei symbol in Illustrator

[image]

Comment: "One line at a time." What specific part of drawing this are you having problems with?

Comment: See like question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29622/how-can-i-create-a-tight-spiral-shape-archimedean-spiral

Comment: Hi user40327, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

1. Draw 5 circles form the center. Start with a 58 x 58 mm and shape of 12 mm for each circle.

[image]

2. Delete the anchor point on the side of the circle by using the direct selection tool. Star with the left side and go on in turns form there:

[image]

3. Align the semicircles, using the selection tool:

[image]

4. Draw a straight 70 mm line from the bottom anchor point of the outer semicircle upwards.

[image]

5. From the top anchor point of the line, draw a 23 mm line to the left.

[image]

6. Join the anchor points, by selection the two points you want to join and hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
7. Select the anchor point at the bottom, you will get a bigger dot inside the edge. (Only in Adobe CC Versions, I think). Click and drag This handle and you are able to round your edge to your liking.

[image]

8. Apply a stroke width of 10pt

[image]

Answer (score 0):

2 options:
1. Drap a circle inside a circle inside a circle, cut and connect between them - this takes more time but will be the most specific
2. The easiest but less specific way is with the with the **spiral tool** which you can control with arrows up and down and then expand

Comment: The spiral tool does not keep the same distance between segments, which makes it impossible to get the intended result.